# Access pagemap in gem5 FS mode

Tags: gem5

I am trying to run an application which uses pagemap in gem5 FS mode.
But I am not able to use pagemap in gem5. It throws below error -

> "assert(pagemap>=0) failed"

The line of code is:

```
int pagemap = open("/proc/self/pagemap", O_RDONLY);
  assert(pagemap >= 0);
```

Also, If I try to run my application on gem5 terminal with sudo ,it throws error-

> sudo command not found

How can I use sudo in gem5 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These problems are not gem5 specific, but rather image / Linux specific, and would likely happen on any simulator or real hardware. So I recommend that you remove gem5 from the equation completely, and ask a Linux or image specific question next time, saying exactly what image your are using, kernel configs, and provide a minimal C example that reproduces the problem: this will greatly improve the probability that you will get help.

I have just done `open("/proc/self/pagemap", O_RDONLY)` successfully with: [this program](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/f8c0502bb2680f2dbe7c1f3d7958f60265347005/kernel_module/user/pagemap_dump.c#L30) and [on this `fs.py` setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/f8c0502bb2680f2dbe7c1f3d7958f60265347005#gem5-getting-started) on aarch64, see also [these comments](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/f8c0502bb2680f2dbe7c1f3d7958f60265347005#pagemap_dump-out).

If `/proc/<pid>/pagemap` is not present for any file, do the following:

- ensure that procfs is mounted on `/proc`. This is normally done with an `fstab` entry of type:

  ```
  proc            /proc       proc    defaults    0   0
  ```

  but your init script needs to use `fstab` as well.

  Alternatively, you can mount `proc` manually with:

  ```
   mount -t proc proc proc/
  ```

  you will likely want to ensure that `/sys` and `/dev` are mounted as well.
- grep the kernel to see if there is some config controlling the file creation.

  These kinds of things are often easy to find without knowing anything about the kernel.

  If I do:

  ```
  git grep '"pagemap'
  ```

  to find the `pagemap` string, which is likely the creation point, on v4.18 this leads me to `fs/proc/base.c`, which contains:

  ```
  #ifdef CONFIG_PROC_PAGE_MONITOR
      REG("pagemap",    S_IRUSR, proc_pagemap_operations),
  #endif
  ```

  so make sure `CONFIG_PROC_PAGE_MONITOR` is set.

`sudo`: most embedded / simulator images don't have it, you just login as root directly and can do anything by default without it. This can be seen by the conventional `#` in the prompt instead of `$`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I did not understand the setup you are using. Are you trying the program on gem5 in FS mode and image being aarch64 image.

Comment: @Rashmi yes, see README.

Comment: I just figured out that the problem is not with permission. Actually the pagemap file is never created.I tried with different linux version and image but nothing seems to work. Is it the image or gem5 that the pagemap file is never created??                                                                                          
Your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: @Rashmi great, now gem5 is out of the equation. I've added two possibilities on the answer, give that a try.

Comment: Hi Ciro, I tried the first method.Earlier my proc was empty. Now it has directories and files. But there is no file called "pagemap" in /proc/self/ .I can see other files but not pagemap.                                                                                                                 And regarding your second point,I cannot find any base.c file.I dont understand the second method

Comment: @Rashmi recompile your kernel with `CONFIG_PROC_PAGE_MONITOR=y`. `base.c` is inside Linux kernel source tree. Familiarize yourself a bit with the Linux kernel source and build procedure ;-)

Comment: Hi Ciro, I recompiled my kernel with CONFIG_PROC_PAGE_MONITOR=y. Now I am getting this error-"Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)". It also says-"Please append a correct "root=" boot option". What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you pass `root=` as the kernel suggested? Just near that line it shows a list of available partitions. Typically `root=/dev/sda`, or `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/vda`.

Comment: Where do I need to pass root="boot option"?  while compiling kernel or while running gem5?

Comment: Do I need to update root="boot option" in fstab file?

Comment: @Rashmi yes. root= tells the kernel where to get the root filesystem which contains init= from. If that is wrong, boot fails. fstab is only used in userland after boot finishes by `mount -a`, traditionally from `inittab`, and only to mount other filesystems besides the root (although there is often an entry there for the root to make the root `rw`). If root= is wrong, boot fails and fstab is never reached.

Comment: I got that point. My question is where should I put root= option?

Comment: Hi Ciro, I am finally able to resolve the issue.Generally speaking, gem5 skips over the bootloader portion of boot and loads the kernel into simulated memory itself.Details about root is gem5/configs/common/FSConfig.py .Just updated the root =boot option and its working fine.We can close the thread now. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: OK! Consider clicking the green tick next the vote count on the answer if you think it solves the issue.